# Does electrostatic polarity in aluminum or alcohol based dye affect adhesion. If so, what would encourage the best adhesion?

Tags: electrostatic-energy

I am trying to find the best method to encourage adhesion of a wood alcohol based dye to 6061 aluminum. The results I have gotten have generally been a somewhat blotchy appearance, and a uniform appearance is desired. Current Method:

Place about 2K parts in a rotating tumbler with a spherical vessel of 2 gallons that has a 3.25" throated opening.
Tumbler rotates a 40 rpms
inject 1 tsp dye. parts are usually coated within 15 seconds
once coated blow compressed air (50 psi) to dry parts. 
Parts are usually dry within 30 seconds.
See results in picture

Would polarity affect adhesion? If so, how would one go about providing the correct polarity?
Would heating the parts affect adhesion?
Would hot air drying affect adhesion?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Certainly, but polarity of what? It might help to pre-treat he aluminium, or use a slightly different dye, or modify the dying/drying process. What options do you have? I'd just try it out, hard to predict the consequence of slower/faster drying, use of more or less solvent, etc.